# Event aggregator for Ext JS

Tags: extjs, eventaggregator

Do you know of any reliable event aggregator implementation for ExtJs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I've found is the [MsgBus](http://examples.extjs.eu/?ex=msgbus) plugin by ozef Sakalos, aka Saki.

It provides a publish/subscribe model for message passing between ExtJS Components.